# Weird behaviour of while loop in office script

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

I use the following code to update cell A1 but it does not work:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) { 

    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    var i: number = 0; 

    while (true) {
        worksheet.getRange("A1").setValue(i);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Nothing happened when the code is run.

However, if I add an irrelevant line

```
console.log("abc")
```

at the end of the loop, as you can see below:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) { 

    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    var i: number = 0; 

    while (true) {
        worksheet.getRange("A1").setValue(i);
        i = i + 1;
        console.log("abc");
    }
}
```

everything will work smoothly.

So, what is actually happening here?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have an infinite loop, though. I'm surprised anything works with it in place.

Comment: My guess is that when you log to the console, it executes pending statements to be executed. So even though you're in an infinite loop, when you log to the console, it executes the update to cell A1 here. I would guess that in a normal procedure this happens after the Main function completes. So it doesn't happen in your first example because you never get out of the infinite loop and the function never completes. But this is all speculation on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To improve performance, Office Scripts only publishes the results of your script after you "synchronize" with it. `console.log()` is one of the ways of forcing that, but there are others.

---

From [Office Scripts in Excel > Troubleshooting > Improve script performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/web-client-performance#remove-unnecessary-consolelog-statements) (emphasis mine):

> ### Remove unnecessary `console.log` statements
>
> Console logging is a vital tool for [debugging your scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/testing/troubleshooting).
> However, it does **force the script to
> synchronize with the workbook** to ensure the logged information is
> up-to-date. Consider removing unnecessary logging statements (such as
> those used for testing) before sharing your script. This typically
> won't cause a noticeable performance issue, unless the `console.log()`
> statement is in a loop.

Likewise, from the article [*Avoid using the context.sync method in loops*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern):

> It's generally a good practice to put have a final `context.sync` just
> before the closing "}" character of the application `run` method (such
> as `Excel.run`, `Word.run`, etc.). This is because the `run` method makes a
> hidden call of `context.sync` as the last thing it does if, and only if,
> there are queued commands that have not yet been synchronized. The
> fact that this call is hidden can be confusing, so we generally
> recommend that you add the explicit `context.sync`. However, given that
> this article is about minimizing calls of `context.sync`, it is actually
> more confusing to add an entirely unnecessary final `context.sync`. So,
> in this article, we leave it out when there are no unsynchronized
> commands at the end of the run.

Your Office document is only visibly updated when the workbook is *synchronized*. This happens when `context.sync` is run, which happens implicitly at the end of your script; it also happens when you make a *synchronized command* like `console.log`. If you were to make your loop finite rather than infinite, then your script would automatically synchronize when your loop's limit is reached, and your workbook would appropriately update exactly once.

If you'd like to see partial progress, you can also force an update in the middle of your script with `console.log` or `context.sync`, but you should be aware that those calls are expensive and you might want to be careful to make minimal use of them as in the linked articles.

Answer (score 4):

The answer above is correct, though I wanted to offer some clarification on the context.sync. Office Scripts presents a synchronous API which does not require the user to explicitly perform the sync operations (and does not expose the context object). Consecutive writes are indeed all batched up and sent once. In your initial sample, you are just adding to the batch forever. Any console.log or read operation to the workbook will force the sync to happen and you'll see the write operation(s) you've batched up to that point.